# WCF uniquely identify clients with certificates issue

Tags: wcf, web-services, authentication, certificate

I've got this WCF webservice which provides a pretty basic lookup-service (so no data is changed on the server-side). The information provided by this service is confidential so I have to take the approriate security measures.

The standard things to do is providing transport and message security by demanding a valid client certificate in the service binding. I create and issue these certificates so I control who can use this service. But (according to me, please prove me wrong here) nothing prevents the clients from exchanging their client certificates with other clients (whom I have not given access to my service). As long as the provided client certificate is valid, the service accepts the connection. An added username/password mechanism does nothing to change this, as these credentials can also be exchanged.

You may say that the client is legally obligated to keep the certificate to himself, but that does not provide enough security for me. Is there a way to specifically control who connects with my service, without having to resort to IP-based access control (as my clients use DHCP issued IP addresses, there is no way to couple the IP to a client/certificate).

My initial quess is to somehow use a unique identifier generated by the client who installs the client certificate (like a GUID) in its certificate store and register this on the server-side so that only the combination of the certificate subject and that unique identifier may access the service. But I have no idea if there is a mechanism to do that.

Edit: since I have no control over the clients I cannot solve this problem easily by altering the code on the client side.

I'm really grateful for any pointers/answers!

Answer (score 2):

I use the `IDispatchMessageInspector` for this. While not being sure whether this is a best-performant approach, it has proven to be working just fine.

My clients use the message header to send their unique GUID.
Each GUID corresponds to each client certificate and these are stored in the Windows Registry.
GUID is generated by the client (I do it using [UuidCreateSequential()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379322%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

I will share my solution with you. This is my service code:

```
    public object AfterReceiveRequest(ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request, System.ServiceModel.IClientChannel channel, System.ServiceModel.InstanceContext instanceContext)
    {
        IList<IIdentity> identities = OperationContext.Current.ServiceSecurityContext.AuthorizationContext.Properties["Identities"] as IList<IIdentity>;
        string clientGuid = request.Headers.GetHeader<string>("Guid", "MyNamespace");
        if (clientGuid == null)
            throw new FaultException("Client GUID not sent!");
        Guid testGuid = Guid.Empty;

        if (!Guid.TryParse(clientGuid, out testGuid))
        {
            throw new FaultException(string.Format("The format of the GUID '{0}' is not valid!", clientGuid));
        }

        IIdentity X509Identity = identities.Where(x => x.AuthenticationType == "X509").SingleOrDefault();
        RegistryKey identityKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\MySoftware\\Identities");
        string storedSubjectName = (string)identityKey.GetValue(clientGuid);

        if (storedSubjectName == null)
        {
            string[] valueNames = identityKey.GetValueNames();
            for (int idx = 0; idx < valueNames.Count(); idx++)
            {
                string testCN = (string)identityKey.GetValue(valueNames[idx]);
                if (testCN == X509Identity.Name)
                {
                    throw new FaultException(string.Format("Certificate '{0}' has already been registered!", X509Identity.Name));
                }
            }
            identityKey.SetValue(clientGuid, X509Identity.Name, RegistryValueKind.String);
        }
        else
        {
            if (storedSubjectName != X509Identity.Name)
                throw new FaultException(string.Format("Certificate '{0}' used by the user registered with the certificate '{0}'", X509Identity.Name, storedSubjectName));
        }

        identityKey.Close();

        return null;
    }
```

The code on the client:
*On app startup*

```
        RegistryKey guidKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("SOFTWARE\\MySoftware\\Settings");
        string clientGuid = (string)guidKey.GetValue("Guid");
        if (clientGuid == null)
        {
            clientGuid = UUID.mGetNewGUID().ToString();
            guidKey.SetValue("Guid", clientGuid, RegistryValueKind.String);
        }
```

*A helper class to get the unique UUID thanks to [this article](http://www.eigo.co.uk/News-Article.aspx?NewsArticleID=63)*

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

static class UUID
{

    // ==========================================================
    // GUID Creation
    // ==========================================================
    private const int RPC_S_OK = 0;
    private const int RPC_S_OUT_OF_MEMORY = 14;
    private const int RPC_S_UUID_NO_ADDRESS = 1739;

    private const int RPC_S_UUID_LOCAL_ONLY = 1824;
    [DllImport("rpcrt4.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int UuidCreateSequential(ref Guid guid);

    [DllImport("rpcrt4.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int UuidCreate(ref Guid guid);

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates the machine GUID.
    /// </summary>
    public static Guid mGetNewGUID()
    {
        Guid guidMachineGUID = default(Guid);
        int intReturnValue = UuidCreateSequential(ref guidMachineGUID);
        switch (intReturnValue)
        {
            case RPC_S_OK:
                return guidMachineGUID;

            case RPC_S_OUT_OF_MEMORY:
                throw new Exception("UuidCreate returned RPC_S_OUT_OF_MEMORY");
            case RPC_S_UUID_NO_ADDRESS:
                throw new Exception("UuidCreate returned RPC_S_UUID_NO_ADDRESS");
            case RPC_S_UUID_LOCAL_ONLY:
                throw new Exception("UuidCreate returned RPC_S_UUID_LOCAL_ONLY");
            default:
                throw new Exception("UuidCreate returned an unexpected value = " + intReturnValue.ToString());
        }
    }

}
```

*In `BeforeSendRequest` of `IClientMessageInspector`*

```
        var guidHeader = new MessageHeader<string>(Service.ClientGuid);
        var untypedGuid = guidHeader.GetUntypedHeader("Guid", "MyNamespace");
        request.Headers.Add(untypedGuid);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply! It looks promising but I have one question: how is the GUID generated and stored on the client? Is there a database involved?

Comment: Thanks! This looks very good! It doesn't totally exclude the option of certificate exchange as the client can still extract the GUID from the registry but the bar is certainly raised! ;)

Comment: Sorry, after some thought I realized your answer does not suit my application, because I have no control over the implementation of the clients. I will add this to the OP.

Comment: @jscheppers The only way to identify the WCF client without modifying the client code is by the IP address. There are many problems with this (you specified one of them - dynamic IP addresses), so my conclusion is that there is no solution for your particular scenario. Also, if this answer of mine is useful to you, don't forget to vote up ;-)